# JAXB how to wrap?

Tags: java, jaxb

I have the following xml :

```
 <parent>
  <wrapper>
    <item>A</item>
    <test>B</test>
    <anotherTest>C</anotherTest>
  </wrapper>
</parent>
```

so is there any option of wrapper? `@XmlElementWrapper( name="wrapper" )`?

Comment: What do you want to wrap? What do you want to do specifically? Have you looked at the ```javax.xml.bind.annotation.*``` to find out if there is such a wrapper?

Comment: I know that for example I can wrap lists, so I thought may be there is an annotation to wrap item, test and anotherTest without creating another subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, at least for lists of specific objects.

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="TravellerList")
@XmlElement(name = "Traveller")
protected List<TravellerType> traveller;
```

Wraps the List in an element called `TravellerList`.

In your example, you don't need a wrapper. Just create a new XMLElement that contains the Elements `item`, `test` and `anotherTest`.